# Does jungle block line of sight?

Tags: civilization-5

Civilopedia says:

> A unit cannot see a target if **a blocking terrain object** is between the
>   two - a mountain or hill, for example, or a forest tile.

So does jungle count as "a blocking terrain object"? The description above doesn't mention it, but it doesn't feel conclusive. After all jungle is counted with hills and forests as *rough terrain* and in real life jungle is as much an obstacle as any forest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, jungle always blocks sight. It has the same behavior like forest in terms of vision.